# WPF print canvas with children instead of window

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, canvas, printing

I want to write a WPF program wherein I want to print a specific part of the program/window. I only want the canvas to be printed.
Unfortunately the whole window gets printed all the time, but I only want the canvas to be printed.

Here is an example of the layout:
[image: Window with input and canvas]

Here is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string name;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Text(double x, double y, string text)
    {
        canvasPrintExample.Children.Clear();
        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
        textBlock.Text = text;
        textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock, x);
        Canvas.SetTop(textBlock, y);
        canvasPrintExample.Children.Add(textBlock);
    }

    private void tbxClientInfoName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        clientInfoName = tbxClientInfoName.Text;

        Text(0, 0, name);
    }

    private void btnPrintCanvas_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog prnt = new PrintDialog();
        if (prnt.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            Size pageSize = new Size(prnt.PrintableAreaWidth, prnt.PrintableAreaHeight);
            canvasPrintExample.Measure(pageSize);
            canvasPrintExample.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, pageSize.Width, pageSize.Height));

            prnt.PrintVisual(canvasPrintExample, "Print");
        }
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

I've tried changing this line in 'btnPrintCanvas_Click'

```
Size pageSize = new Size(canvasPrintExample.Width, canvasPrintExample.Height);
```

And I've tried hardcode the size:
    Size pageSize = new Size(200, 400);

But nothing changes. All I get is this .pdf print:
[image: .pdf output print]

**Edit - added .xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Factv001"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="810" Width="1010" Background="LightGray">
<Grid>
    <Canvas Name="canvasPrintExample" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="750" Margin="452,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="530.3" Background="White"/>
    <TextBox Name="tbxClientInfoName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,31,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225" TextChanged="tbxClientInfoName_TextChanged"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnPrintCanvas" Content="Print" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="167,682,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnPrintCanvas_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The second picture doesn't look like the first one. So what makes you think that the "whole window gets printed"? Where are the TextBox and the Button in the PDF?

Comment: The size is the same and the position of the text 'Name' is centered, like in the window.